# Q. SharePoint Online - Setting LockState property via PowerShell not successful and no error reported

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, read-only, powershell-script

I have been attempting to `Unlock` a `ReadOnly` site in SharePoint Online.

I have tried with PNP

```
Connect-PnPOnline $SiteURL -Credential $Cred
Set-PnpSite -LockState "Unlock"
```

I have tried with Connect-SPOService through the Admin portal log in

```
Connect-SPOService -Url $adminUrl -Credential $credentials
Set-SPOSite -Identity $SiteURL -LockState "Unlock"
```

Neither of these return an error nor `Unlock` the site.

- The Admin Account is both a SharePoint Admin and a Site Collection
  Admin on the site.
- The site was locked using the `Site Closure and Deletion` settings page for the site and clicking the Close Site
  button.

Does anyone have any direction on what could be blocking all attempts to Unlock the site?

Answer (score 0):

If you lock the by using **Site Policy** via **Site Closure and Deletion**, then you will need to manually unlock the site by clicking the “**Open this site**” button.

Note that these are two different methods to lock a site in SPO, one way does not overwrite the other.
Same happens when you use PowerShell to lock a site, you will need to run PowerShell again to unlock it.

Comment: The site was in fact closed using Site Policy via Site Closure and Deletion.  Ultimately i need to add a user into the visitors group to the site to view the content, but i do not want to reset any of the Site Deletion dates which would happen if we re-open the site.

Any Tips?

Comment: @EFighter I’m afraid that is not possible. The site will return access denied error when you try to perform any action on it, which is the point of setting it to Read-Only.